# At the eleventh hour

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, québec

What are some colloquial ways to say "at the eleventh hour" (the last moment or almost too late, see, e.g., https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eleventh-hour)?
One way should obviously be "à la dernière minute" but I am wondering if "à la onzième heure" is considered an anglicism or rather a québécisme ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectivement, [*à la dernière minute*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/eleventh_hour/578060). Pour la référence à la [*onzième heure*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/onzi%C3%A8me), *le dernier moment*, on indique que c'est par référence à la bible, [Mathieu 20, 1-16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthieu%2020%3A1-16&version=LSG) (6 : « Étant sorti vers la onzième heure, il en trouva d'autres qui étaient sur la place [...] » ; 9 : « Ceux de la onzième heure vinrent, et reçurent chacun un denier. ») (TLFi) ; Wiktionnaire indique que la locution adjectivale [*de la onzième heure*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_la_onzi%C3%A8me_heure) serait péjorative et familière. Je suis un locuteur du Québec et je ne connais pas l'expression. Il est peu probable que ce soit un anglicisme ou un québécisme.

Il y a l'expression [*être moins une*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_moins_une) signifiant « être déjà presque trop tard » et on dit qu'[*être moins cinq*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_moins_cinq) en serait un synonyme ; dans les deux cas c'est fort probablement la référence aux minutes précédant l'[heure](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/une) fatidique, en tournure impersonnelle et employé absolument : *il était/c'était moins une/cinq* (Wiktionnaire). Je pensais personnellement que l'expression était « il était minuit moins une » ; je ne sais pas si c'est chez moi l'influence de *two minutes to midnight* qui semblerait être une chanson d'un groupe de métal anglais que je connais.

Comment: Merci. Le groupe est Iron Maiden. Up the Irons alors:-)!

Comment: [;-)](https://youtu.be/Msy451mv_Ts).

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu "être moins cinq" dans ce sens figuré ("moins une" oui).